# How can I upload using File using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I  would like to upload a file :

```
<button id="interior-file-upload-browse-button-announce" class="a-button-text" type="button">
Upload Interiorr manuscript
</button>
```

i tried to use this solution but it doesn't work:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("interior-file-upload-browse-button announce").send_keys("/Users/maclab/Desktop/Design/scale/interior.pdf")
```

Comment: Usually the good page implementation is giving you the opportunity to send file into some page element(usually with type of file). Try to find element of `type=file` if the one exists and send_keys into it

Comment: Can you update the error trace pls

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why your's wouldn't work and without the error trace its hard to tell the problem. Here is a another solution. Use [fine-uploader](https://docs.fineuploader.com), running selenium tests with pytest :

```
    elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
    elm.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/tests/sample_files/Figure1.tif")
```

No form submission or Enter key is needed in my case.